# OS X Terminal Ignoring SOCKS Proxy Setup

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, osx-lion

Previously I've used an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -D 1234 user@remoteHost
```

As a system wide proxy in OS X by going to System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies -> Tick SOCKS Proxy and enter localhost 1234 -> Ok -> Apply

[image: SOCKS Proxy Setup]

But it seems this no-longer works for me, the terminal appears to be completely ignoring the network config to use the proxy but other programs are using it correctly.

Can anyone offer any suggestions or a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle

Comment: You can set a proxy configuration in SSH command or config file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34781933/728162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs have to be specifically written to check the OS X network settings to get the proxy settings; most terminal command are standard unix (/posix) programs that haven't been modified to know anything about the way OS X manages proxies.  However, it depends on the particular program.  Some have command-line options that let you specify a proxy, like this:

```
curl --socks5 localhost:1234 "http://www.apple.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring answer.