# Force all applications to use MacOS X-configured proxy

Tags: osx-lion, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X Terminal Ignoring SOCKS Proxy Setup](https://superuser.com/questions/377199/os-x-terminal-ignoring-socks-proxy-setup)

I've set up a proxy in the MacOS X (10.7) network preferences, but command-line applications and daemons seem to ignore this (e.g. git, rsync, etc.). Of course, many of these tools has its own way of setting up a proxy through command line options or configuration files, but sometimes this is not the case. Is there a way to define the proxy settings on a low-level that guarantees that **any** http/https request is routed through the proxy?

Comment: Not a duplicate SOCKS and http proxies differ

Comment: It's the same problem though. It's simply not possible to teach all your (Unix) programs to use the OS X specific proxy settings.

Comment: So there is no way to get all unix programs to use the OS X settings, but is it possible to define the settings at a lower level so that they do get taken into account by *all* programs?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's nothing special about HTTP; it's just a protocol over TCP. So, any program that opens a TCP connection to a remote server *may* end up using HTTP. Yet, for your HTTP proxy to work, you need to redirect this TCP connection before the first byte is sent, and therefore you don't know whether it's an HTTP connection.